# How to save changes in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, save

I know how to add contents to the HTML file that is currently loaded in the browser, now I just want to find out if there is a way to save those changes to the .html file itself. Basically when the file is closed and loaded again later it should still have the dynamically added content.

Comment: Use `Server-side script` with `database`.

Comment: Is this a locally loaded file (with `file://...`)?

Comment: @Mr Lister , yes it is.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola I don't want to run it on a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also `indexedDB` if you need to store more complex/large amounts of data, Client side. There is no need for server side scripting for this.

SessionStorage and LocalStorage only store strings, so if you needed to store objects you would have to stringify it first. However with indexedDB it wont.

It's quite a bit more involved than sessionStorage (too much to explain here) but these links helped me when i was looking into it.

Basically you connected to the database, handle any required upgrades to it (this handles fist time creation and setting up of transactions), then you get your object store and finally perform your reads, updates etc against that. The majority of the work is in the setup and upgrading of the DB.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-indexeddb--net-34673

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this with HTML alone. Use server-side scripting language (e.g. PHP) with a database (e.g. MySQL). Store your page content on the database and feed contents to your html page using the server-side script.

(you can also use XML file to store the data. no need of database)

Comment: Could you say how can i save the changes with using xml and write an example code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

```js
window.onload = function () {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("savedItem"))
    document.querySelector("#store").value = sessionStorage.getItem("savedItem");
  document.querySelector("#store").onkeyup = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("savedItem", document.querySelector("#store").value);
      alert("Saved!");
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<div sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms">
  <input type="text" id="store" placeholder="Type something and press Enter to save..." />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but this only saves the data while the page stays open or is refreshed. I want to be able to close the page and open it later and still have the content.

Comment: `LocalStorage` will persist when the tab or window is closed. Exactly the same API.